# Converting very wide logos to square formats

Tags: logo

We all know how much easier our lives became when social media decided that our clients brands needed to be adequately represented in square format! So far I have always managed to pull of this tricky conversion, but this time I am faced with a particularly tricky (inherited) logo:

[image]

You can see here that the logo is comprised of three elements. The "Bosch" logo which has to be included contractually, the companies (unfortunately) extended name (stylised), and a tagline that could be omitted in square format.

I have relied before on a method of using only the company initials in the "avatar" format, stylised in the same way as the logo, but in this case, with the (ironically) square Bosch logo needing to be included I am stumped. These, for example, are awful:

[image]

I would love to here what tricks/techniques any of you have for dealing with this issue. I think it goes without saying that this client is not Bosch! If they were then firstly I'd me much wealthier, and secondly I'd be very happy my logo was exactly square and take the rest of the day off! In this case both the Bosch *and* the stylised company mark have to be included. Somehow!

Comment: Many companys has a vertical version of their logo in their graphic profile. There isn't any such that in this case?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Thus far they have been able to use this layout on everything. In fact they have vertical "flags" but that  is simply the logo sideways!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to have to simplify the image in some way, such that it looks good and is readable/recognisable at any size. The two examples you posted fail in this regard.

This is something you would need to speak to your client about. For example, how much creative licence do you have? Is the Bosch Service logo inviolate?  You may even need to check the branding guidelines for Bosch to see what is allowed and what isn't. Indeed it's possible you may not be allowed to use that logo at all at really small sizes. It could potentially be a legal minefield if you don't abide by their brand guidelines.

Consider whether or not the social networking ID/avatar needs to be the actual company logo.  You could use another related image, and put the company logo on the businesses' social networking page instead, perhaps contained in the header/cover image.

Perhaps look at what other Bosch service centres have done on their own social networking pages.  Obviously if you want to stand out from the crowd, it might not be a good idea to simply repeat what others have done.

Comment: Accepted answer because "You could use another related image, and put the company logo on the businesses' social networking page instead, perhaps contained in the header/cover image." - really did point me in the right direction. It broke my mental block and I was able to use an image of the clients "flags" - that have their logo on, and some blue sky/clouds for this purpose. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11):

According to what you describe in the question, I think it's a combination of two logos in a square area rather than a single logo adaptation to a square format. It seems to be a company and its franchisor or representative. In fact, the adaptation to each logo separately has already been done, the first one fits in a square and the other choosing just the initials "VL" as you show in the example. Anyway I will try to answer in a general way and not particularly to this case.

There are certain conceptual premises to consider that can directly affect the design:

**Hierarchy:** should a hierarchy be established or avoided between the logos? Are both at the same level?

[image]

**Flexibility**: both (or one of the) logos are strict and unmodifiable or may allow some "alteration" in terms of design, such as text alignment, elements location ...

[image]

**Position**: must they respect an order: left-right / first-second / top-down?

[image]

Once obtained these answers, adjust the design trying to:

- Altering as less as possible the structure of each logo:

[image]

- Balance the shapes and blank areas taking as reference the square limits, the paper edge in publishing design

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Polar format will fit inside a square and there's some room even left over.

An example (sorry for poor transformation accuracy

[image]